# SQL - Return group of records from different tables not including specific row

Tags: sql

I am new at programming and SQL, so sorry if I do not include enough info.

[I have these 2 tables that are linked by an OrderID. Table1 includes OrderIDs and customer information such as FirstName, LastName, and Address. Table2 includes OrderIDs and order details such as ItemName, Price, and Quantity.

Each OrderID in Table2 might have multiple ItemName entries with the same OrderID.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdxev.png)

CustInfo

```
OrderID     FirstName   LastName    Address
1           Bob         Pratt       123
2           Jane        Doe         456
3           John        Smith       789
4           Barbara     Walters     147
```

Orders

```
OrderID     ItemName    Price       Quantity
1           Milk        4.00        1
1           Eggs        5.00        2
2           Cheese      5.00        1
2           Bread       5.00        1
3           Milk        4.00        2
4           Yogurt      5.00        2
```

I'm trying to make a query that will send back a list of every Order, listing the OrderID and ItemName among other info, as long as the order doesn't include a specific type of item (which would be in ItemName). So if an OrderID contains 2 ItemName, one of which is the one I do not want, the entire order (OrderID) should not show up in my result.

For example, based off the img included, if I wanted to show all orders as long as they do not have Milk as an ItemName, the result should only show OrderID 2 and 4.

```
2   Cheese  5.00 1
2   Bread   5.00 1
4   Yogurt  5.00 2
```

This is what I have tried but this would return OrderIDs even though Milk is technically part of that OrderID.

```
SELECT OrderID, FirstName, LastName, ItemName, Price, Quantity  
FROM CustInfo
JOIN Orders
ON CustInfo.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
WHERE ItemName != 'Milk'
```

Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to SO; here you find something useful on [ask] and how to build a [mcve]; some starting points: post your table structure and sample data as formatted text, not images, so that people can easily build a test case, and post you attempts, results, errors and problems you are having. PS: is it oracle or mysql?

Comment: Since you said you're new: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/4955425)

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clean up edits. I will read through those links as well

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm trying to edit original post as with more information as they are asked.

Comment: I have updated my original post to hopefully be clearer about my data and what I'm looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, my issue is resolved. I see how each of the below answers resemble each other although are slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select o.OrderID, o.ItemName, c.FirstName, c.LastName -- include other fields if needed
from Orders o
left join CustInfo c on o.OrderID = c.OrderID
where o.OrderID not in (
  select OrderID from Orders where ItemName = 'Milk'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.OrderID, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T1.Address, T2.OrderID, T2.ItemName, T2.Price, T2.Quantity
FROM Table2 as T2
  LEFT JOIN Table1 as T1 ON T1.OrderID = T2.OrderID
WHERE T2.OrderID <> (SELECT OrderID FROM Table2 WHERE ItemName='Milk');
```

Comment: However, you will want to use a parameter for the item to be excluded instead of hardcoding it in.

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: @SimonHänisch Okay. SELECT the items you are wanting to see in the query result and since Table2 contains the variable that can be the excluding factor we use it for the FROM statement. Then we join the information from table 1 that contains the same orderID as table 2 with a left join on those matching criterias. Then, to answer his question, we exclude the results with Milk as the ItemName

Comment: This answer used to be correct, but the OP has since changed the wording of the question. Please recheck.

Comment: Updated to exclude his updated question. Thanks @AlvinThompson

Comment: I don't think you can use `<>` on a list of values. You have to use `NOT IN` instead. In other words, the `SELECT...WHERE ItemName='Milk'` clause can return multiple IDs.

Comment: @JamesN edit your answer and include the explanation in there, please. You should always give an explanation when sharing code.

Comment: @AlvinThompson I tested it and it worked for me using MySQL. As he didn't provide a SQL version earlier I went off MySQL.

Comment: @SimonHänisch The answer is self explanatory as he already stated he understands queries and just needs the last part. If the answer required more indepth explanation I would. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole order to not show up, rather than just individual rows, you can use WHERE NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, d.ItemName, d.Price, d.Quantity
FROM Orders o
JOIN OrderDetails d ON o.OrderID=d.OrderID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM OrderDetails d2
    WHERE o.OrderID=d2.OrderID
    AND d.ItemName = 'Milk'
)
```

Comment: Also, totally guessing on table/column names.